how to refer to typename's typename is template in C++?
I am working on a project which is nested templates. How to refer to typename's typename?
See examples below.
template<typename T>
class point1{
   public:
     T x, y;
     point1(T v1, T v2):x(v1), y(v2){}
}
template<typename T>
class point2{
   public:
     T a, b;
     point2(T v1, T v2):a(v1), b(v2){}
}
template<typename pointarray>
class coordinates{
   public:
     pointarray & _pp;
   void printsum(){
   using pointtype = typename pointarry::value_type;
   // pointarray could be like vector<point1<int>>, deque<point2<double>>
   // now pointtype could be point1 or point2
   // there will be compiling issues in below.
   auto intORdouble = pointtype::value_type;
   intORdouble ssumm = 0;
  }
}

The more I learned about template in C++, the more complicated it seemed to be.

What is auto intORdouble = pointtype::value_type; even supposed to be? pointtype is point1<T> or point2<T>, but those don't have a value_type typedef in them. Even if they did, why do you have auto instead of using here? The previous line suggests you know what using is.

the question is unclear. There are many typos in your code please fix them.

Maybe you think that ::value_type extracts a template parameter from a type? It doesn't in general,  vector just has a using value_type = T; in it that makes it work.

"...the more complicated it seemed to be." it will be already a bit simpler if you start from how you are going to instantiate the templates, how you are going to use them. I suppose somewhere there will be int or double but there is no int or double anywhere in your code. Do you have a main where you instantiate the templates? If yes,please show it. If not, write it. Writing templates without instantiating them is like flying a plane blindfolded

for us its not even clear how the three tempaltes are related. I suppose you will instantiate either coordinates<point1< some type>> or coordinates<point2< some type>> but I know this only from your previous question. And here it is even less clear why you think you need point1 and point2 rather than just one of them.

type template typename's type name is its name, obviously

You have to define it.
template<typename T>
class point1{
   public:
     using value_type = T; 

     T x, y;
     point1(T v1, T v2):x(v1), y(v2){}
};

I assume pontarray is some default container, they have exactly that. If you must to reach in guts of some non-standard but  not controlled by you template type, you may use template template parameters (that's an intentional repeat), or have to do that manually.
To compare types, there is a type_traits tool:
auto intORdouble = std::is_same<typename pointtype::value_type, int>::value;

but do you actually need it to be a non-static run-time value? You can declare static constant in a number of ways.
using isInteger = std::integral_constant< bool, 
                       std::is_same< typename pointtype::value_type,
                                     int >::value >;

isInteger  here would be a type whose whole purpose it to contain a static constexpr value of type bool returned by is_same.
